# Making an Elastic Search filtered query in Ajax

Tags: ajax, search, post, filter, elasticsearch

I need to make an Elastic Search query with Ajax. What I'm trying to do is search for a specific category name, and return the list of names associated with that category. The structure in Elastic Search is that each _source has a name fields (the name of the category), and an items fields. It also has name.raw so that I can search by exact name.

This is my request:

```
var query = {
    query: {
        filtered: {
            filter: {
                term: { "name.raw": category }
            }
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.0.240:9200/dropdowns/category/_search",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Success");

    },
    error: function(data) {
        // should be only one item in hits
        $(data.hits.hits).each(function(index, hit) {
            alert(hit._source.items);
        });
    },
    data: query
});
```

For now, I'm trying to simply get it to work enough to alert me to the items in the hit. I'm getting a 400 Bad Request error. What's wrong with my Ajax call?

Comment: Shouldn't your ajax request type be `get`?

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with your AJAX call. Elasticsearch returns a 400 if your query is bad. You should be looking at the `data` in your error function for the problem with your query. It probably has to do with an incorrect mapping, since youre trying to do a nested search. Also, `data.hits.hits` will only be a thing in success. An error will never return hits.

Comment: Right, so what's wrong with the query?

Comment: Nothing inherently, from what I can see. You need to log the error message to the console in the `error` callback to see what the elastic search server is telling you. If you want to easily test your query, use `curl` or Elasticsearch Sense http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/#_sense

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, could you tell me how to do that? How do I log the error message to the console?

Comment: I posted a code sample and some explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from Jonathon Lerner, I figured out that the problem with my query was that it had to be stringified. So, I simply changed it to

```
data : JSON.stringify(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to send the query in the URL using a GET method, with this syntax:

```
var query = '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter:{"term":{"name.raw": category}}}}}';

$.ajax({
        url: `http://192.168.0.240:9200/dropdowns/category/_search?
              source_content_type=application/json&source=${query}`,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code:

```
var query = {
    query: {
        filtered: {
            filter: {
                term: { "name.raw": category }
            }
        }
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.0.240:9200/dropdowns/category/_search",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success');
        $(data.hits.hits).each(function(index, hit) {
            console.log(hit._source.items);
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    data: query
});
```

you should be able to debug the problem with your query in the Javascript Console, as well as see successful output. Here are some directions on how to see the JS console in different browsers: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Edit: It seems like those directions are for Windows specifically. I know that on Mac, Command+Option+j opens the Chrome JS console. Im sure if your browser/OS isnt covered here you can find the correct shortcut on Google.

Comment: OK, so I'm getting success when I run GET, but GET returns ALL the categories, not just the one I'm looking for. When I do POST, it fails, but the console isn't telling me why it's failing; it just says "bad request"

Comment: The console should log two different things on failure. In terms of why it returns more than you want when you use GET...I would have to see your mapping, some sample docs, etc. to be able to actually debug an elasticsearch query.

Answer (score 1):

> The HTTP libraries of certain languages (notably Javascript) don’t allow GET requests to have a request body.

See this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html

So I think it's correct to use POST method here, you simply forget to stringify the request body.